# Show that $\mathbb{R}$ and the open interval $(-1, 1)$ have the same cardinality.

Tags: functions, real-numbers, cardinals, interval-arithmetic

I am a little confused about using functions to show that two sets of intervals have the same cardinality.

I believe that if we can find a bijective function $f$ such that $f: \mathbb{R} \to (-1, 1)$, then they have the same cardinality? For example,

$$ f(x) = \tanh x $$

However, can we also say that if we can find a bijective function $f$ such that $f: (-1, 1) \to \mathbb{R}$, then they also have the same cardinality? If yes, can you provide an example?

Comment: Yes. If $f : A \to B$ is bijective, then $f^{-1} : B \to A$ is bijective, for instance; the implications and thought-process are fairly straightforward

Comment: $f(x) = tan(\pi x/2)$ is a bijective map from $(-1,1)$ to $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the function $f: \mathbf{R} \rightarrow (-1, 1)$ defined by
$$
f(x) = {x \over 1 + | x |}
$$

Clearly, $f$ is well-defined.

It is easy to verify that $f$ is a bijection.

In fact, the inverse of $f$ is obtained as $g: (-1, 1) \rightarrow \mathbf{R}$ defined by
$$
g(y) = f^{-1}(y) = {y \over 1 - |y|}  
$$

Hence, it follows that $\mathbf{R}$ and $(-1, 1)$ have the
same cardinality.

Comment: Is it possible to show that $\mathbf{R}$ and $(-1, 1)$ have the same cardinality with a function $f$ such that $f: \mathbf{R} \to (-1, 1)$ though?

Comment: For $g(y)$, do we have $y \in \mathbf{R}$, or $y \in (-1, 1)$?

Comment: Sorry, it was obviously a typo.. Thanks for spotting it